# Reroute to component passing response data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, axios

Is there any way I can pass the response from a post request to another component and then reroute to that component?

Here's a shortened example:

This is the main app...

```
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

import Login from './components/login.component'
import Homepage from './components/homepage.component'

const App = () => (
    <Router>
        <Route path="/" exact component={ Login } />
        <Route path="/homepage" component={ Homepage } />
    </Router>
)

export default App
```

here is the form with the post request...

```
import React from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

const Login = () => {

    const handleSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault()
        axios.post( API, {
            user_id: 'demo',
            user_pwd: 'demo'
        })
        .then( res => {
            console.log( res.data )
            // ???
        })
    }

    return(
        <form onSubmit={ handleSubmit }>
            ...
        </form>
    )

}

export default Login
```

and here is where I want to get the response data somehow

```
import React from 'react'

const Homepage = props => {
    console.log( props )
}

export default Homepage
```

Comment: You can use context or a global state management like redux for example. 
You could store your data from your response in the global state and then connect Home component to the state and get the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to handle such scenarios would be to have a provider in your App where you can store this data and then use it in whichever component you want

For your case, a context provider or even redux if you are already using it would be good

UserContext.js

```
export const UserContext = React.createContext();
```

UserProvider.js

```
export default class UserProvider extends React.Component {
   state= {
      userData: null
   }
   updateUserData = (userData) => {
      this.setState({userData})
   }
   render() {
       return <UserContext.Provider value={{userData: this.state.userData, updateUserData: this.updateUserData}} >{this.props.children}</UserContext.Provider>
   }

}
```

Main App

```
const App = () => (
  <UserProvider>
    <Router>
        <Route path="/" exact component={ Login } />
        <Route path="/homepage" component={ Homepage } />
    </Router>
  </UserProvider>
)

export default App
```

Login

```
const Login = () => {
    const {updateUserData} = useContext(UserContext);
    const handleSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault()
        axios.post( API, {
            user_id: 'demo',
            user_pwd: 'demo'
        })
        .then( res => {
            console.log( res.data )
            updateUserData(res.data);
        })
    }

    return(
        <form onSubmit={ handleSubmit }>
            ...
        </form>
    )

}

export default Login
```

and in HomePage

```
import React from 'react'

const Homepage = props => {
    console.log( props )
    const {userData} = useContext(UserContext);
    console.log(userData);
}

export default Homepage
```

Answer (score 1):

It'd be a good idea to think about some kind of a "store manager" like Context / Redux.
If you wrap it around some components, than it'd be much easier to deliver necessary data to components that need it.

Answer (score 0):

The way for doing that is using a store on the parent component. You can accomplish that using the [**useContext**](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html) hook.
Here is a [good tutorial](https://daveceddia.com/usecontext-hook/) on how you can make it happen. The algorithm would go like this:

- Perform your login with Axios and set the user fetched from your API to the context store
- Redirect the user to the specific route
- fetch the user from the context